# python requests.get ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, request

Here is my code:

```
import requests
r = requests.get("https://api.github.com/events")
```

I use requests module but it fails. I don't know why terminal show

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you add details like python version, conda version, requests version etc. As it may help in finding the issue. The coed sippet itself does not seem to have an error, there may be other factors affecting it. Also you haven't saved the file in VSCode...

Comment: You only posted two lines of your code and asking us to help you. The error you get has no relation to those two lines you posted. Please post complete code.

Comment: It is a bug in the requests library that affects only windows systems. That's why in Linux or other compatible systems it works without problems. Problem is, it affects pip that depends on requests.

Comment: The bug is being corrected by the requests module developers and will be available for the next version:
https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/6104

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the requests module itself in the line it says the error is in the module's utils.py file. It's a bug that should be filed for the requests module. Note that, in line 68, it tries to get the internet proxy settings from system and parse the registry value to int. But, in that case, instead of the windows registry query return 0 or 1, it's returning '', thus, the int() function fails. They have to make a conditional statement before trying to parse the return value to int. If '' goes to 0, if '0' goes to int('0') and '1' goes to int('1'). Or catch the ValueError and treat the problem there. So this module is currently working only for linux and other systems that don't pass through this routine.

[image]

And that did the trick:
[image]

The link to the issue that I opened in the project's GitHub
https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/6104

**EDIT:** One of the project's contributors recognized it as a bug and it's scheduled to be corrected for the next milestone.

**EDIT:** The correction was published

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly help, but may narrow it down. I tried this code on Linux and it works just fine.

```
import requests
r = requests.get("https://api.github.com/events")
print(r)
```

<Response [200]>

Edit: Python3 and Linux Mint 20.2

Answer (score 0):

Use This Code Instead Of Your Own:

```
import requests
url = 'https://api.github.com/events'
r = requests.get(url)
print(r.response)
```

Maybe Work.
But, I use your code  in  my interpreter and it was fine & work(:

Comment: I try your code, I get same issue. ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''